# How to fix the warning of " format %d expects argument of type int "

Tags: c

This warning appears while debugging the code but as a function it works

"format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int'"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void * StackEntry;
#define MAXENTRY 100

typedef struct stackentry
{
    int top;
    StackEntry entry[MAXENTRY];
} Stack;

void CreateStack(Stack *);
void Push(StackEntry, Stack *);
void Push(StackEntry, Stack *ps);
void Pop(StackEntry *, Stack *ps);
int StackEmpty(Stack *);
int StackFull(Stack *);

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    StackEntry e = (int *)22;
    Stack s;
    CreateStack(&s);
    Push(e, &s);
    //Push (22,&s);
    //Pop(&e,&s);
    a = StackEmpty(&s);
    b = StackFull(&s);
    printf("%d %d %d", b, a, s.entry[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the error message: `%d` *does* expect an argument of type `int`. Did you copy/paste the error message or (mis)type it from memory?

Comment: (continuing discussion from the "answer" where you posted additional code, but which doesn't really belong there) Storing integers into `void *` like this is not a terribly good practice.  If you want to keep doing it that way, the way to fix your error is just to use `printf("%d", (int)p1.x)`.  Or, the perhaps better way will be to call `malloc(sizeof int)` every time you push an int on your stack -- but there are a number of other corresponding changes you'll have to make.

Comment: Mr. Steve Thanks very much it's working now :)
but what does it mean (int) before pointer to integer, what is the difference between it and between casting (int *) ?

Comment: As written, your stack is an array of pointers-to`int`, or `int *`.  The syntax `(int *)` is a cast to convert something *to* that type.  You are -- rather wrongly -- trying to jam vaues of type `int` into slots designed to hold values of type `int *`.  The compiler doesn't like this, and complains, which is why you have to use the explicit cast to say "yes, I really intend to do this wrong thing, so please take my `int` and pretend it's an `int *`".  Then, when you take the `int *` back out of the array, you have to convert it *back to an int* -- and that's what the `(int)` cast is for.

Answer (score 2):

If what you meant was for `Point` to consist of an integer value `x`, then `Point` should be declared as follows.

```
struct Point { int x; };
```

In your declaration, `x` is not an integer but a pointer to an integer.

Then, you can assign the value `2` to `x` as follows.

```
p1.x = 2;
```

And the `printf` statement will work.

Comment: Look, this is a part of another program but I tried to simplify it in a separate code

Comment: @belal Hassan - Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `Point.x` as type `int *`, i.e. a pointer to an `int`, but you assign an `int` to it and print it as an `int`.

Change the type to `int`.

```
struct Point { 
    int x; 
};
```

Comment: Please do not post code in a commet.  Rather post the code as part of the question